# Folder Structure in Index.js file, Module not Found Error

Tags: reactjs

How to write the folder directory structure in `index.js` file in the time of importing a functional components file.

Below is the code with Error. My folder directory structure is in this way. So how to access import and export of file in my code or `index.js` file.

> Folder Directory Structure -
> `E:\reactapp\AvatarDemo\my-app`

#### Error

```
Failed to compile.
    
        ./src/index.js
        Module not found: Can't resolve '.Avatar' in 'E:\reactapp\AvatarDemo\my-app\src'
        
        Failed to compile
        ./src/index.js
        Module not found: Can't resolve '.Avatar' in 'E:\reactapp\AvatarDemo\my-app\src'
        This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

#### Functional Components File

```js
import React from 'react';
const Avatar = () =>{
 <>
   return 
      <h1>Hello Welcome to the world of Functional Components</h1>
      <p>Naffy Kausar</p>      
  </>
}

export default Avatar;


//Index.js File
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import './index.css';
        //import App from './App';
        import Avatar from './Avatar';
        import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
        
        ReactDOM.render(<Avatar/>,document.getElementById("root"));
        
        serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Writing `Avatar` Component like below

```js
import React from 'react';
const Avatar = () => (
  <>
      <h1>Hello Welcome to the world of Functional Components</h1>
      <p>Naffy Kausar</p>      
  </>
)
```